# localhost page isn't working, trying to connect to mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to connect to mongodb through PHP with the "vendor/autoload.php" but as soon as I require the file I get that the localhost page isn't working

```
<?php require '../vendor/autoload.php' ?>

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->users->user;
```

[image: screenshot of the localhost page]

Comment: 1. Which webserver? 2. What's in the error log? 3. Why did you not look into the error log? 4. Why didn't you look how to enable errors to be displayed in PHP?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question should be clear and not a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `;` and closed PHP tags too early, which might be a good start to fix first.

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->users->user;
```

For further investigation, look into your error logs or enable error reporting!

```
<?php 
// Put these lines to the top of your script
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
```